# Выбранный чекбокс по умолчанию суммирует по формуле

Tags: jquery, checkbox

На форме есть выпадающие списки при их выборе к цене добавляется соответствующее значение селекта. Не получается сделать так, чтобы выбранный по умолчанию чекбокс добавлял к стоимости 100 автоматически при загрузке страницы, так же можно галочку снимать и из стоимости должно вычитаться -100.

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //выбранный чекбокс добавляет к сумме:       
  $("#yslygi:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });

  //общая сумма
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}

$("#yslygi").click();

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
  <option value="6300">Белава</option>
  <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option value="0">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="yslygi">Борт</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="bort" />100<br/> Стоимость
<span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сначала генерируете событие `click`, а только потом добавляете обработчик события, который пересчитывает сумму. Можно, например, просто поменять эти строки местами:

```js
function calculate() {
  var sum = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
    sum += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
  //выбранный чекбокс добавляет к сумме:       
  $("#yslygi:checked").each(function() {
    sum += 100;
  });

  //общая сумма
  $('#final_price').html(sum);
}

$('select,input').change(function() {
  calculate();
});

$("#yslygi").click();
```

```html
<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
  <option value="6300">Белава</option>
  <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option value="0">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1900</option>
  <option value="1000">2000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="yslygi">Борт</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="bort" />100<br/>
Стоимость <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

И если немного прибраться в коде:

```js
$("select, input").on("change", function() { 
  var sum = 0;
  $("select").each(function() {
    sum += parseInt(this.value);
  });
  if ($("#yslygi").prop("checked")) {
    sum += 100;
  };
  $("#final_price").text(sum);
});

$("#yslygi").trigger("click");
```

```html
<label for="model">Выберите модель кровати</label>
<select name="model_krovat" id="model" class="form-control">
  <option value="6300">Белава</option>
  <option value="7000">Чердак</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="shirina">Выберите ширину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="shirina_krovat" id="shirina">
  <option value="0">900</option>
  <option value="1000">1000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="dlina">Выберите длину</label>
<select class="form-control" name="dlina_krovat" id="dlina">
  <option value="0">1900</option>
   <option value="1000">2000</option>
</select><br/>
<label for="yslygi">Борт</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="yslygi" name="bort" />100<br/>
Стоимость <span id="final_price">6300</span> Руб.

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!